# How to draw a personalized path line in rviz (for example 30cm wide)

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, path, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a possibility to draw the path in a hector-map in rviz with a userdefined wide?
The reason is I'm tracking a VR100 vacuum cleaning robot (aka neato) cleaning my house. Because the wide of it's brushes is 30cm I want to draw the path in the map in the same wide to see, which areas were cleaned and which areas ware skipped due to obstacles to remove them. Nice to have were also a configurable alpha value of its color, which will be increased when a path is drawn more then once to see overlapping cleaned areas.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/78771/how-to-draw-a-personalized-path-line-in-rviz-(for-example-30cm-wide)/) by [FlashErase](https://answers.ros.org/users/6319/flasherase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-09-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Points%20and%20Lines) explains how to publish [markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) that RViz can visualize. What you need is a LINE_STRIP with scale.x=0.3, I think.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FlashErase](https://answers.ros.org/users/6319/flasherase/) on 2013-09-13**:
Thank you. I inspected display_path.cpp to find out how to get the path data to draw the line_set (in the example the data was generated by the marker itself). This is so tricky, that I'll better use the time to get a consistent map out of my lidar data.

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-22**:
I'm not sure what you mean... the tutorial I propose shows quite straightforwardly how to show a path. Anyway, can you mar the question as solved if that is the case? Maybe can help others in your same case.

**Comment by [FlashErase](https://answers.ros.org/users/6319/flasherase/) on 2013-09-23**:
I couldn't find any hints how to get the data for drawing these line-strips out of the slam system and not by calculating demo data by sin/cos-functions. But because neither gmapping nor hector_mapping are able to process my lidar data into a usable map and path this question anyway is obsolete.

**Comment by [FlashErase](https://answers.ros.org/users/6319/flasherase/) on 2013-09-23**:
I tried to mark this question as "Solved" but I'm problably blind and can't find a button or link for it:
http://imageshack.us/a/img856/3130/i5z5.png

And there were no informations in the help or the FAQ how to mark a question as "Solved". So I'll mark this question as "Closed".

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-23**:
Just click the "check" symbol below the answer's votes counter. It gets green.